# Find all values of $x$ at which the tangent line to the given curve has intercept $ y= 2$

Tags: derivatives

Find all values of $x$ at which the tangent line to the given curve has intercept $y = 2$

I am confused about the $y$-intercept $2$

the function $$f(x) = \frac{(2x + 5)}{(x + 2)}$$

The derivative is $$f'(x)  = \frac{- 1}{(x^2 + 4x + 4)}$$

Now what should I do next with the given $y$ intercept?

Sorry for a easy question just have misconception on derivative's relationships with a tangent and what is the derivative at a point gives us?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative

Answer (score 1):

equation of tangent of f(x):

$$\forall t \in R,   y_x(t) =f'(x).t+b$$

Here $b=2$ because it is y-intercept 2 (go through (y,t)=(2,0)):

$$y_x(0) = f'(x).0 + b = 2$$

Finally you have to solve (go through f(x)):

$$y_x(x)=f(x)$$

or again:

$$ f'(x).x+2= f(x)$$

more explicit, you have to solve:

$$2-\frac{x}{x^2 + 4x + 4}=\frac{2x + 5}{x + 2}$$

Comment: Sorry couldn't get it what is A & B here

Comment: @Ali: look updated

Answer (score 1):

The general equation of a line passing through ($x_1,y_1$) and having slope m is$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$

The general equation of a tangent to the curve at ($x_1,y_1$) is,
$$Y-y_1=- \frac{1}{x^2 + 4x + 4}(X-x_1)$$where $(X,Y)$ is any point on the tangent.

The tangent line passes through (0,2). Hence substituting $X=0$ and $Y=2$ into the above equation, we get
$$y_1-2=\frac{1}{4}x_1$$
Now the slope of the tangent is $\frac {1}{4}$. 
Hence
$$\frac {1}{x^2 + 4x + 4}=\frac {1}{4}$$
Solve for x to get the required values.

Comment: is $x_1=0$ or $x=0$?

Comment: Yeah fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @GTX OC: $2-y_1=\frac{1}{4}x_1$ instead of $y_1-2=\frac{1}{4}x_1$

Comment: @GTOX OC: I don't know how do you go from $y−y1=m(x−x1)$ to $y-y_1=- \frac{1}{x^2 + 4x + 4}(x-x_1)$? I would say $$\forall t \in R, y-y_1=- \frac{1}{t^2 + 4t + 4}(x-x_1)$$ . Because here if the variable of the tangent equation is x then your equation of tangent is not linear. So your solution is wrong.

Comment: In $Y-y_1=- \frac{1}{x^2 + 4x + 4}(X-x_1)$, the $x$'s should be $x_1$.

Answer (score 1):

At $\left(x_1, \dfrac{2x_1+5}{x_1+2}\right)$, the slope of the curve $y=\dfrac{2x+5}{x+2}$ is $\dfrac{-1}{(x_1+2)^2}$. So the equation of a line passing through that point with that slope (in point-slope form) is $$y-\frac{2x_1+5}{x_1+2}=\frac{-1}{(x_1+2)^2}\left(x-x_1\right)$$

If this line has $y$-intercept $2$, then it passes through $(0,2)$. Use that, and then see what $x_1$ has to be. There is only one solution for $x_1$, and hence only one point meeting the required condition.

Comment: I would be highly thankful if could please tell how having the $y$ intercept as $2$ means that the tangent line has $x$ intercept as $0$.

Comment: @jiten There is no mention of "$x$ intercept" here. The $y$-intercept is where the curve crosses the $y$-axis. Any place on the $y$-axis has $x$-coordinate $0$. Note that $x$-coordinate of the $y$-intercept is not the same as $x$-intercept.